# LoactionManager Api19 NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-location

maybe somebody can tell my why below code works on Api above 25, but on Api 19 which a right now i'm testing i have null after that i try to get longitude and latitude?
I had read official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) but but each method which i used (target Api 25) is compatible with Api 19

```
Location loc = gpStracker.getlocation();
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
```

and gpsTracker class:

```
public class GPStracker implements LocationListener {

    Context context;

    public GPStracker(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public Location getlocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Uprawnienia nie przyznane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSenabled;
        isGPSenabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSenabled) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            return location;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Proszę włączyć GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(dis), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You Should use Fused Location Api by Google

Answer (score 0):

The function `getLastKnownLocation` could potentially return `null`, even if you called `requestLocationUpdates`. Also, since in your `getLocation` function, you could return null as well, I would recommend you add a check as follows:

```
Location loc = gpStracker.getlocation();
if (loc != null) {
    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
}
```